# Getting style from container from contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, css, extract, edit, contenteditable

I need to get the style of a container that is set to be content-editable. Basically, I need to extract:

```
color: red; font-weight: bold;
```

from this, in a content-editable div:

```
<span style='color: red; font-weight: bold;'>
    ...
</span>
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance!

PS: it might also be nice to have the css as an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var styleObj = getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style;
```

What do you need? ^^